# Display Polyline length in feet using Leaflet.Draw toolbar

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am creating a map that the user will be able to draw lines on using the Leaflet.Draw toolbar. I would like the running distance of the line to be displayed in feet/miles instead of the default yards/miles. Looking at the project in GitHub, it seems to me the following code should do this:

```
 var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw: {
                polyline: {
                    shapeOptions: {
                        color: 'red',
                    },
                    metric: false,
                    feet: true,
                }
            }            
        });
```

But the length is still displayed in yards. Any insight into why this is would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin are you using?

Note that:

- Leaflet.draw version [v0.2.4 / 0.2.4-dev](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/v0.2.4) (as used in the plugin GitHub [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/)) does not have the `feet` option yet.
- Leaflet.draw version [v0.3.0 / 0.3.0-dev](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/v0.3.0) (latest release for Leaflet 0.7) has the `feet` option.
- Leaflet.draw from [`leaflet-master`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/leaflet-master) branch, for compatibility with Leaflet 1.0, is based on version 0.2.4 and does not have the `feet` option.

Comment: Gotcha. I was using a github.io repository, and I didn't realize it was the older version of Leaflet.draw