# Error while trying to delete/edit shape using leaflet draw - ESRI

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri, leaflet.draw, esri-leaflet

I am trying to delete/ edit a shape created using leaflet draw.

I get the following error when trying to edit the shape created.

I'm using leaflet 1.0-rc1 and leaflet draw version 0.3.2.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([28.7041, 77.1025], 13);
    L.esri.basemapLayer("Topographic").addTo(map);
    //Edit Toolbar

    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            position: 'topleft',
            polygon: {
               allowIntersection: false,
                drawError: {
                    color: '#b00b00',
                    timeout: 1000
                },
                showArea: true
            },
            circle: {
                shapeOptions: {
                    color: '#662d91'
                }
            },
            polyline: false,
            rectangle: true,
            marker: false,
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems
        }
    });
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Leaflet 1.0, you have to use Leaflet.draw [`leaflet-master`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/leaflet-master) branch, as mentioned on the repo [home page](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw):

> Support for Leaflet 1.0 is in development at the leaflet-master branch.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PmHj1FhOoeZBEsAnEu1z?p=preview

That means that you may not have all the latest features from the plugin unfortunately (e.g. [Display Polyline length in feet using Leaflet.Draw toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336028/display-polyline-length-in-feet-using-leaflet-draw-toolbar/38338205#38338205))